# Display contents of file and also copy it to the clipboard

Tags: macos, command-line, copy-paste

I would like to create a helper function that displays my public key in the terminal and also copies it to the clipboard. How would I do that?

I tried `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | pbcopy`, but this only copies the key to the clipboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just paste the clipboard into the terminal window-

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | pbcopy; pbpaste
```

or use tee in the pipe with process substitution

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | tee >(pbcopy)
```

or forget about using pipes altogether

```
pbcopy <~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub; pbpaste
```

Comment: While this works, isn't there a more "unixy" way to pipe to 2 commands in parallel?